# Read binary data on C++ where different columns have different data types

Tags: c++, file-io

We have a binary file that represents data arranged in columns.

Each column has a different data format, for example:

- column 1: 8 bytes (unsigned long int)
- column 2: 4 bytes (int)
- column 3: 4 bytes (float)

What would be the best way to read these files in C++, I can do it in matlab, but I don't really have much clue of how to do it in C++

Comment: I would recommend converting the file into a human-readable format first (because binary formats come and go and ASCII text stays forever).

Comment: I do not know if it is true, but the argument is that the data is unholy large and is only numbers anyway.

Comment: Converting floats to text is a tricky business. Some compilers don't do this especially accurately.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming that these values are in order:

```
unsigned long int dataMember0 = 0;
int dataMember1 = 0;
float dataMember2 = 0.0;

std::ifstream fileStream("file.bin", std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
fileStream.read((char*)&dataMember0, sizeof(unsigned long int));
fileStream.read((char*)&dataMember1, sizeof(int));
fileStream.read((char*)&dataMember2, sizeof(float));
```

You cast a char pointer because it is being read as an array of bytes (char is one byte). If you want to loop this process: `while(fileStream) {...}` will excute until there is no more to read

Comment: This does, of course, assume that the bytes in the file are ordered in the same way that the bytes in the host architecture are.

Comment: It compiles, but in the first filStream.read I get a segmentation fault. Any idea why would this be happening?

Comment: Even better, use sizeof(dataMember0). That way, if the type changes, the correct number of bytes is read.

Comment: You are getting a segmentation fault because I made a very stupid mistake! In my excitement I forgot the address-of character: "&" :) It is corrected now